# Disappearing characters while typing in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, formatting

I am trying to place numbers on successive rows by typing the number and tapping the enter key, then typing a number and so on. I can type the first number, but when I tap the enter key the following numbers  do not show up.  The overset text box becomes active immediately. If I click on that, it creates a new textbox, but there are no numbers showing up. I can type text, hit the enter key and type more text, and hit the enter key, etc., but numbers don't work.

Comment: Do you have a paragraph rule applied or additional spacing applied in the text editing menu?

Comment: Just to be clear: you can type _text_ with paragraph breaks and it works fine, but if you type _numbers_ with paragraph breaks, it becomes overset? That sounds very bizarre. Does this happen in all documents or just a specific one?

Answer (score 1):

When editing/setting text in **InDesign**...

The **<kbd>Enter</kbd> key** means.... **Jump to the next text frame**. 
If there is no "next text frame", the overset text indicator is seen. 
Repeatedly hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> will *repeatedly* "jump to next frame".

Use the <kbd>**Return**</kbd> **Key** if your desire is merely a new line/linefeed.

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is the *wrong key* to use for a "new line".

---

I'm somewhat assuming that the reason things are fine for you with *text* is that it is human nature to use the **Return** key when typing text... and it's equally human nature to use the **Enter** key when using the numeric keypad.

In many applications, Return and Enter are interchangeable, but an InDesign user should be aware that the **Return** key is *not* the same as the **Enter** key when editing/setting text in InDesign.

---

This also assumes you have **two separate keys** for <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd>. If your keyboard only has *one* key labeled for both Return AND Enter, the "jump" behavior is achieved by holding the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> and then hitting the <kbd>Return/Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, **DO NOT** hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the *numeric pad*, this has a different effect from the regular <kbd>Enter</kbd> key:

- Regular <kbd>Enter</kbd>: creates a new paragraph, otherwise called jumping to a new line.
- Numpad <kbd>Enter</kbd>: this in InDesign is attributed to a `Column Break` which immediately moves the cursor outside of the current text box and assumes you have another text box threaded. Do not use the numpad <kbd>Enter</kbd> if you don't understand this effect.
- Every time you hit the numpad <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you are generating overset text, unless you have a threaded setup already in place.

Also, you can see the entire contents of a text box stripped down of any formatting, by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> while editing a text. This opens up the `Story Editor` and this will show anything you have in there regardless of how many times <kbd>Enter</kbd> has been used.

Also, make sure you turn on `Hidden Characters` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, which immediately highlights line breaks, column breaks, forced line breaks, tabs, etc.

Read this: https://creativepro.com/a-tale-of-two-enter-keys/